# How to click with cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

[image: Click on link using Cypress]

I'm trying to click on the 181 Fastighet using cypress as you see in the picture.
writing like this
cy.get('.col-lg-11 col-md-11 text-left text-nowrap text-truncate ').click();
but i get an error
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: .col-lg-11 col-md-11 text-left text-nowrap text-truncate , but never found it.

The test can not find the div where it should click on.
I tried many different ways but it does not work!
Any Ideas ??

Comment: Is the text 181 Fastighet unique in that web page ?

Comment: @AlapanDas How can i know that ? It seems like its click on the text and not on the link

Comment: Can you try- `cy.contains('181 Fastighets', {matchCase: false}).click()`

Comment: Thank you! I needed to make a lite bit edits so let it work! But a big thank u for u :)

Comment: Please post the final answer here, so that it will help others as well.

Comment: cy.contains('181 Fastighets', {matchCase: false}).click({force: true}); here was the last solution

Comment: One more question is how to let cypress press Enter ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple approach:

```
cy.contains("181 Fastighet").should('be.visible').click()
```

Happy Testing!

@mustafa for your 2nd question related to "Press Enter":

```
cy.get('#password').type('password123{enter}')
```

Comment: Thanks! but how to let cypress press enter after entering an input text ?

Comment: Try this :
cy.get('#password').type('password123{enter}')

Comment: For reference check this stuff: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Form-Submission